# How do I issue a command only if an app is found?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell

I need some help with a bit of shell script.

The code below works, and if sed is found then it continues with the script but if it doesn't exist it will exit.

```
  if ! [ -x "$(command -v sed)" ]; then
    echo "Error: sed is not installed, please install sed." >&2
    exit
  fi
```

What would I have to change to make it if the system finds ufw than it will run those commands.

```
    if ! [ -x "$(command -v ufw)" ]; then
      ufw allow 80/tcp
      ufw allow 443/tcp
    fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the exclamation mark, which means "not". So now instead of checking if the command is "not" there, we are checking if it does exist.

```
   if [ -x "$(command -v ufw)" ]; then 
      ufw allow 80/tcp
      ufw allow 443/tcp
   fi
```

Another option, if you want to catch it first and exit if your conditions aren't  met.

```
   if ! [ -x "$(command -v ufw)" ]; then 
        echo "Your error message here"
        exit # Stop execution
   fi
        # below code only runs if command exists
        ufw allow 80/tcp
        ufw allow 443/tcp
```

Comment: I can do that but i would rather have a command for it too.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood. What do you mean by a command for that too?